# Variable in state undefined React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to store product from an API in the state of my React component and then map them in the render function of the component but somehow `this.state.products` is `undefined`.

This is my components code (CategoryProducts.js):

```
class CategoryProducts extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {}
        this.products = new Products(); 
    }

    async componentWillMount(){
        await this.products.getProductsInCategory(this.props.name).then(
            (val) => {
                this.setState({products: val}); 
            }
        )
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Container className='content-container'> 
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}>
                        <h4 className="mb-0">{this.props.name}</h4>
                        <hr></hr>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={2}>
                        Some space for possible filters in the future 
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={10}>
                        {this.state.products.map(function(item, i){
                            console.log(i); 
                        })}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

The call to the API is async this is the corresponding code:

Products.js:

```
export class Products extends API {

    getProducts() {
        return this.get('/products')
    }
    getCategories(){
        return this.get('/products/categories'); 
    }
    getProductsInCategory(_category){
        return this.get('/products/withcategory/' + _category); 
    }
}
```

And this method inside the API class:

```
async get(_endpoint) {
        let response = await fetch(this.API_url + _endpoint);
        return response.json();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The first time render() is called, the API call might not be ready yet. You need to take this into account in your render() function.

The easiest way is something like:

```
{this.state.products && this.state.products.map(function(item, i){
                        console.log(i); 
                    })}
```

This will only do the mapping when `this.state.products` has some value.

You could also show some loading component while the products are being loaded by adding something like this in your render() function.

```
{ !this.state.products && <SomeLoadingComponent /> }
```

Comment: Or initialize his state: `this.state = {products: []}`.

Comment: That would also work, yes. However, as a followup on that, it is often useful to distinguish between (a) the data has not been requested from the API yet, or (b) the data has been requested, but is empty (i.e. there is no result). It is common to use something like `undefined` for situation (a) and an empty array or an empty object for situation (b).

Answer (score 0):

You are turning the componentWillMount into a promise so that part won't be executed as such by RN:

```
 async componentWillMount(){
        await this.products.getProductsInCategory(this.props.name).then(
            (val) => {
                this.setState({products: val}); 
            }
        )
    }
```

Try this:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            products: [] //Or whatever suits you best
         }
        this.products = new Products(); 
    }

 componentWillMount(){
        this.products.getProductsInCategory(this.props.name).then(
            (val) => {
                this.setState({products: val}); 
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **componentWillMount()** is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before **render()**, therefore calling **setState()** synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering

You should avoid to place a API call in [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) life cycle method.

Instead use,[`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
async componentDidMount(){
        await this.products.getProductsInCategory(this.props.name).then(
            (val) => {
                this.setState({products: val}); 
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define variable in

```
class CategoryProducts extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state = {products : '';}
     
}
enter code here
```